# Android xml parsing missing tags

Tags: android, xml, parsing, dom, doc

I am trying to parse a xml file using dom parser. The xml fles contains lots of missing tags.
What i want to do is that , if i get any missing tag( like in example below 2nd artist tag do not contain image tag) i want to set String image as some value like "na", so that i can put values in an array or a list.

Below is example

```
<list>
<artist>
<id>1</id>
<name>name1</name>
<image>name1.jpg</image>
</artist>
<artist>
<id>2</id>
<name>name2</name>
</artist>
</list>
```

My current code :

```
        NodeList list = element.getElementsByTagName("artist");
        if (list != null && list.getLength() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {

                Node item = list.item(i);

                NodeList properties = item.getChildNodes();

                for (int j = 0; j < properties.getLength(); j++) {

                    Node property = properties.item(j);

                    String name = property.getNodeName();

                    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("__id")) {

                        try {

                            String strTitle = property.getFirstChild()
                                    .getNodeValue();
                            System.out.println(strTitle);

                        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                            // TODO: handle exception

                            System.out.println("Null ID");
                        }

                    }

                    else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("__name")) {

                        try {

                            String strTitle = property.getFirstChild()
                                    .getNodeValue();
                            System.out.println(strTitle);

                        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                            // TODO: handle exception

                            System.out.println("Null Name");
                        }

                    }

                    else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("__image")) {

                        try {

                            String strTitle = property.getFirstChild()
                                    .getNodeValue();
                            System.out.println(strTitle);

                        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                            // TODO: handle exception

                            System.out.println("Null Image");
                        }

                    }
                }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a String variable set to your default, assigned just before you enter the loop that parses child tags of artist. Then within your loop, if you find an image child, replace that String variable with the provided value.

Edit: code based on the original:

```
        NodeList list = element.getElementsByTagName("artist");
        if (list != null && list.getLength() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {

                Node item = list.item(i);

                NodeList properties = item.getChildNodes();

                String strImage = "na"; // default

                for (int j = 0; j < properties.getLength(); j++) {

                    Node property = properties.item(j);

                    String name = property.getNodeName();

                    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("__id")) {

                        try {

                            String strTitle = property.getFirstChild()
                                    .getNodeValue();
                            System.out.println(strTitle);

                        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                            // TODO: handle exception

                            System.out.println("Null ID");
                        }

                    }

                    else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("__name")) {

                        try {

                            String strTitle = property.getFirstChild()
                                    .getNodeValue();
                            System.out.println(strTitle);

                        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                            // TODO: handle exception

                            System.out.println("Null Name");
                        }

                    }

                    else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("__image")) {

                        try {

                            String strTitle = property.getFirstChild()
                                    .getNodeValue();
                                                            strImage = strTitle;
                            System.out.println(strTitle);

                        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                            // TODO: handle exception

                            System.out.println("Null Image");
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Image: " + strImage);
```

Comment: Answer looks promising.. But can u please provide me any working example or any shipnet(sorry am new to android)..

Comment: Hey mah , i got it working thanx a lot mate.
Little change tho instead of setting String strImage = "na"; outside the loop i guess it should be declared inside because value of next null strImage gets previous value and is not getting initializes as "na".(older values are reoccurring if i get a black tag)
Did this and its working fine.. :)

Comment: @ZealDeveloper yes, you're of course right about the position of setting strImage. I've updated my post.